# Hibernate/Spring DataSource and RDS Replica

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, amazon-rds

I would like to setup a RDS Read Replica to forward some of the read requests to it. I've annotated all my "read" Dao methods with:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

Now I am struggling with datasource configuration. I expected that it would be really easy, but it seems it isn't. How can I tell the datasource/hibernate that there is a read replica available on certain endpoint?

Currently my configuration looks like:

```
<bean id="mainDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://${master-url}:3306/${db-name}?useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false"/>
    <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    <!--  these are C3P0 properties  -->
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="3"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="3600"/>
    <!--  1 hour  -->
    <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="7200"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="600"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false"/>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mainSessionFactory" name="mainSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" depends-on="mainDataSource">
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com....</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.tinyInt1isBit">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.transformedBitIsBoolean">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">40</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any help/advice would be highly appreciated!

Best Regards,
Maksim